# I want to include an OTP module in my web application can anyone explain how to begin?

Tags: php

How to include an OTP module for my web application.I want to validate a users phone number while registering in my web site.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how can i use OTP or PIN send via SMS using PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31176663/how-can-i-use-otp-or-pin-send-via-sms-using-php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For including an OTP module there are SMS service providers and subscription packages that you can use at feasible prices. 
My suggestion is `https://www.ssdindia.in/transactional-sms/`.
Go for Transactional SMS in order to send an OTP message to all the users or else your OTP will not reach a user who has activated DND for his mobile number.
Refer the documentation and sample codes to include the API in your application.